# How to report back the EXIT code of a multi program script?

Tags: bash, exit-code

On a linux shell I have essentially the following script

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e

python script.py arg1 &
python script.py arg2 &
python script.py arg3 &
wait
echo $?
```

in which some python programs can run in parallel, and I wait until the completion of the programs.

However, when I have only one *failing* programm for testing purposes which fails, the reported exit status is 0 (SUCCESS). I suspect that is the exit status of the `wait` command. That is not what I want. I want to report an error (i.e. exit status unequal zero), if ANY of the programs did fail.

Is there a *simple* way to achieve this?

Comment: Can't you capture the exit status of each command?

Comment: It will be like 10 commands in the end. But well I guess I have no choice.

And how to do that?

Comment: I think you can play around with `$!` which is the background PID.

Comment: Maybe an easier solution is to make a change to the script (it is actually the same script called with different arguments) which change a variable/ write to a file?

Comment: `parallel python script.py ::: arg1 arg2 arg3 || echo one failed`